# not used mysql comment ( <- not statement)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know MySQL comment like `#`, `--` but `#` and `-` cannot be used inside a comment.

I want to use this comment when I am going from PHP to MySQL.

special php option:

```
magic_quotes_gpc = off
```

Comment: Why would you want your comment to be sent as part of your MySQL query? I hope I've understood you correctly here.

Comment: You can't nest MySQL `/* block comments /* like this */ example */` but all other comment styles `-- should nest # fine # because -- they are line-based`.  It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @CodeNewbie one reason you might want SQL comments to be sent to the server would be for debugging... sometimes it's handy to have comments appear in the MySQL General Log or Slow Query Log.  A mod_perl example, `USE db_name /* $$ */;` would write the web server child PID into the general log, letting you later correlate it with the MySQL thread id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL supports three types of comments: `--`, `#` and `/*...*/`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comments.html